# currently trying to create a box plot for my class and cannot find problem with my code

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
df=read.csv("group.csv",header=TRUE)
plt.boxplot(df.group_a,
            main = "Sales Data",xlab = "Group A",ylab = "Sales",col = "yellow",border = "red",notch = TRUE)
plt.boxplot(df.group_b,
            main = "Sales Data",xlab = "Group B",ylab = "Sales",col = "blue",border = "red",notch = TRUE)
plt.boxplot(df.group_c,
            main = "Sales Data",xlab = "Group C",ylab = "Sales",col = "black",border = "red",notch = TRUE)
plt.boxplot(df.group_d,
            main = "Sales Data",xlab = "Group D",ylab = "Sales",col = "green",border = "red",notch = TRUE)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention these are four separate box plots so I have four blocks of code

Comment: what happens when you run the code? please format your question as code with proper indentation to make it easier to read. It would probably help to focus on one box-plot at a time.

Comment: I changed the format but the question is still unclear. what is your purpose and what you get?

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful if you reformatted this answer as code. You can do that by simply typing ```python, then hitting `Return` to go to the next line, pasting in your code, hitting `Return` again, and then typing ``` once more.

If I do that to your question and move things around a bit, it formats as

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=read.csv("group.csv",header=TRUE)

plt.boxplot(df.group_a, main = "Sales Data", xlab = "Group A", ylab = "Sales",
            col = "yellow", border = "red", notch = TRUE)

plt.boxplot(df.group_b, main = "Sales Data", xlab = "Group B", ylab = "Sales",
            col = "blue", border = "red", notch = TRUE)

plt.boxplot(df.group_c, main = "Sales Data", xlab = "Group C", ylab = "Sales",
            col = "black", border = "red", notch = TRUE)

plt.boxplot(df.group_d, main = "Sales Data", xlab = "Group D", ylab = "Sales",
            col = "green", border = "red", notch = TRUE)
```

This has the advantage of making your question readable and even gives you some attractive syntax highlighting. To learn more about how to format questions like this check out https://www.markdownguide.org/.

Now, as for your question, your issue is that your syntax and function calls are mostly incorrect.

`df = read.csv("group.csv", header=TRUE)` should be `df = pd.read_csv("group.csv")`. You could theoretically pass `True` to the `header` argument since Python interprets that as the integer value 1, but...don't. That's not what that argument is for. Refer to the documentation for this function at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html to learn more.

`notch=TRUE` should be `notch=True`. In Python the boolean values are `True` and `False`, and the capitalization is important. You can learn more about these at https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-bool.html.

Lastly, you have a pile of arguments to these `plt.boxplot()` functions that don't exist. You can learn more about the arguments accepted by this function at https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html.

I can't really troubleshoot your answer without a copy of the dataset, but here's a working example that I took straight from https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/gallery/pyplots/boxplot_demo_pyplot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-boxplot-demo-pyplot-py.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

# fake up some data
spread = np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
data = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low))

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.set_title('Notched boxes')
ax2.boxplot(data, notch=True)
```

This gives us the following:
[Notched Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxlIS.png)

I hope this helps! Good luck on your data science adventures.